# Only output points near borders, excluding points near coast

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line, select-by-location, point

I would have liked to ask for help, being confronted to a problem with ArcGis. I have in fact a shapefile of countries and a bunch of points. I would have liked to keep only the points that are located near the border with another country. In other words, I would have liked to exclude the points on the coasts (seaward)

Do you have any idea ? Before I used the Select by Location tool to keep only the points within a certain distance of the source shapefile.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  This seems to be a near duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288121

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Intersect tool as described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129678/122597

> Normally, performing an intersect with polygons will only return the overlapping area. But if you change the `output_type` from `INPUT` to `LINE`, then you can get just the collinear borders between polygons.

Get the border lines and then do "Select by Location".